# What do event keycode constants mean?

Tags: extjs

There is a list of keycodes in `Ext.event.Event`.
However it doesn't contain all of the keycodes, for example `NUM_MINUS` is present, but `MINUS` is not.

1. Why doesn't the list contain every keycode?
2. Am I limited only to the listed keycodes?

Comment: Not sure, but probably due to different layouts. You should be able to determine MINUS using e.getKey equals 189 on an us keyboard. You can add constants or equivalent by your own.

Comment: Are you talking about this: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/modern/Ext.util.KeyMap.html

Comment: No, I mean constants here: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/modern/Ext.event.Event.html#properties